# Detect at least one match between each data frame row and values in vector

Tags: r, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```
x1 <- c("a", "c", "f", "j")
x2 <- c("b", "c", "g", "k")
x3 <- c("b", "d", "h", NA)
x4 <- c("a", "e", "i", NA)
df <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4, stringsAsFactors=F)

df

x1 x2   x3   x4
1  a  b    b    a
2  c  c    d    e
3  f  g    h    i
4  j  k <NA> <NA>
```

Now I have an arbitrary vector:

```
vec <- c("a", "i", "s", "t", "z")
```

I would like to compare the vector values with each row in the data frame and create an additional column that indicates whether *at least one* (ANY) of the vector values was found or not.

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
  x1 x2   x3   x4 valueFound
1  a  b    b    a          1
2  c  c    d    e          0
3  f  g    h    i          1
4  j  k <NA> <NA>          0
```

I would like to do it without looping. Thank you very much for your support!

Rami

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way to do this:

```
df$valueFound <- apply(df,1,function(x){
  if(any(x %in% vec)){ 
    1 
  } else {
    0
  }
})
##
> df
  x1 x2   x3   x4 valueFound
1  a  b    b    a          1
2  c  c    d    e          0
3  f  g    h    i          1
4  j  k <NA> <NA>          0
```

Thanks to @David Arenburg and @CathG, a couple of more concise approaches:

- `apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x %in% vec) + 0)`
- `apply(df, 1, function(x) as.numeric(any(x %in% vec)))`

Just for fun, a couple of other interesting variants:

- `apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x %in% vec) %/% TRUE)`
- `apply(df, 1, function(x) cumprod(any(x %in% vec)))`

Comment: Why `if` `else`? Why not just `apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x %in% vec) + 0)`?

Comment: or `as.numeric(any(x %in% vec))` instead of `+0`

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, I added your solutions above.

Answer (score 9):

This would be faster than an `apply` based solution (despite it's cryptic construction):

```
as.numeric(rowSums(`dim<-`(as.matrix(df) %in% vec, dim(df))) >= 1)
[1] 1 0 1 0
```

---

### Update -- Some benchmarks

Here, we can make up some bigger data to test on.... These benchmarks are on 100k rows.

```
set.seed(1)
nrow <- 100000
ncol <- 10
vec <- c("a", "i", "s", "t", "z")
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(letters, NA), nrow * ncol, TRUE),
                        nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Here are the approaches we have so far:

```
AM <- function() as.numeric(rowSums(`dim<-`(as.matrix(df) %in% vec, dim(df))) >= 1)
NR1 <- function() {
  apply(df,1,function(x){
    if(any(x %in% vec)){ 
      1 
    } else {
      0
    }
  })
}
NR2 <- function() apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x %in% vec) + 0)
NR3 <- function() apply(df, 1, function(x) as.numeric(any(x %in% vec)))
NR4 <- function() apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x %in% vec) %/% TRUE)
NR5 <- function() apply(df, 1, function(x) cumprod(any(x %in% vec)))
RS1 <- function() as.numeric(grepl(paste(vec, collapse="|"), do.call(paste, df)))
RS2 <- function() as.numeric(seq(nrow(df)) %in% row(df)[unlist(df) %in% vec])
```

I'm suspecting the NR functions will be a little slower:

```
system.time(NR1()) # Other NR functions are about the same
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.172   0.000   1.196
```

And, similarly, Richard's second approach:

```
system.time(RS2())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.918   0.000   0.932
```

The `grepl` and this `rowSum` function are left for the benchmarks:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(AM(), RS1())
# Unit: milliseconds
#   expr       min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
#   AM()  65.75296  67.2527  92.03043  84.58111 102.3199 234.6114   100
#  RS1() 253.57360 256.6148 266.89640 260.18038 264.1531 385.6525   100
```

Comment: Ahh `as.matrix`... I was breaking my head to vectorize this. Brilliant

Answer (score 5):

Since you don't want a loop, you could get creative and paste the  columns together by row, and then use `grepl` to compare it with `vec`

```
> as.numeric(grepl(paste(vec, collapse="|"), do.call(paste, df)))
[1] 1 0 1 0
```

Here's a second option that compares the rows to the unlisted data frame

```
> as.numeric(seq(nrow(df)) %in% row(df)[unlist(df) %in% vec])
[1] 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: +1. I like the `grepl` option and had thought of something similar, but I don't like what happens with `NA` values in `paste`. If `vec` contained `N` or `A`, we would have trouble :-)

Comment: Thanks.  That's true about the NAs, but we could also write that into the regex if we wanted to.

Answer (score 3):

As another idea, trying to preserve and operate on the "list" structure of a "data.frame" and not converting it to atomic (i.e. `sapply`, `as.matrix`, `do.call(_bind, ...)` etc.) could be efficient. In this case we could use something like:

```
as.numeric(Reduce("|", lapply(df, function(x) x %in% vec)))
#[1] 1 0 1 0
```

And to compare with -the fastest so far- Ananda Mahto's apporach (using the larger "df"):

```
AL = function() as.numeric(Reduce("|", lapply(df, function(x) x %in% vec)))
AM = function() as.numeric(rowSums(`dim<-`(as.matrix(df) %in% vec, dim(df))) >= 1)
identical(AM(), AL())
#[1] TRUE
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(AM(), AL(), times = 50)
#Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# AM() 49.20072 53.53789 58.03740 66.76898 86.04280    50
# AL() 45.24706 49.34271 51.43577 55.05866 74.79533    50
```

There does not appear any significant efficiency gain, but, I guess, it's worth noting that the 2 loops (in `Reduce` and `lapply`) didn't prove to be as slow as -probably- would be expected.