# How to create a string from row values in a dataframe ignoring NAs

Tags: r, dataframe

This is my dataframe:

```
x1 <- c("a", "c", "f", "j")
x2 <- c("b", "c", "g", "k")
x3 <- c("b", "d", "h", NA)
x4 <- c("a", "e", "i", NA)
df <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4, stringsAsFactors=F)

df

  x1 x2   x3   x4
1  a  b    b    a
2  c  c    d    e
3  f  g    h    i
4  j  k <NA> <NA>
```

Using

```
apply(df, 1, paste, collapse = "_")
```

gives me

```
[1] "a_b_b_a"   "c_c_d_e"   "f_g_h_i"   "j_k_NA_NA"
```

I would like to ignore the NAs so the last resulting element should be "j_k" instead of "j_k_NA_NA".

Thank you very much for your support.

Rami

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your code,

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse="_") )
#[1] "a_b_b_a" "c_c_d_e" "f_g_h_i" "j_k"
```

Another option would be

```
df[is.na(df)] <-''
 gsub("^_+|_+$", "", do.call(paste,c(df, sep="_")))
#[1] "a_b_b_a" "c_c_d_e" "f_g_h_i" "j_k"
```

#### EDIT

If there are inner NAs, perhaps this works

```
gsub("^_+|_+$|_+(?=_)", "", do.call(paste,c(df, sep="_")), perl=TRUE)
```

Or based on @David Arenburg's comments

```
gsub("NA_|_NA", "", apply(df, 1, paste, collapse = "_"))
```

For example

```
v1 <- c(NA,'a', 'b', NA, NA, NA, 'c',NA, 'd', NA)
v1[is.na(v1)] <-''
gsub("^_+|_+$|_+(?=_)", "", paste(v1, collapse="_"), perl=TRUE)
#[1] "a_b_c_d"
```

Comment: +1. Your second option seems like it would be the way to go. The first one would suffer because of the repeated calls to `na.omit` on a dataset with many rows.

Comment: Your last `gsub` needs some modifications to capture multiple subsequent `NA` values in inner columns.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto Thanks for the comments.  I did update the `gsub`.  Hopefully, it would work, though didn't test it extensively.

Comment: Maybe also `gsub("_NA", "", apply(df, 1,  paste, collapse = "_"))`

Comment: @David Arenburg I think that needs some modification `gsub("_NA", "", paste(v1, collapse="_"))#[1] "NA_a_b_c_d"` May be `gsub("NA_|_NA", "", paste(v1, collapse="_"))`

Comment: `v1 <- c(NA,'a', 'b', NA, NA, NA, 'c',NA, 'd', NA)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a suggestion using `zoo` package

```
library(zoo)
gsub("NA_|_NA", "", rollapply(t(df), width = 4, FUN = paste, collapse = "_"))
##      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4] 
## [1,] "a_b_b_a" "c_c_d_e" "f_g_h_i" "j_k"
```

Comment: I haven't added this to my benchmarks, but it strikes me as potentially slow (?)

Comment: @AnandaMahto, it could be because of `t`, but I don't know for sure. I don't think that in this case it matters much

Answer (score 1):

@akrun's second option would most likely be the fastest, but you can also consider something like this:

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(data.table(
  rn = rep(1:nrow(df), ncol(df)), 
  val = unlist(df, use.names = FALSE)))[, paste(val, collapse = "_"), by = rn]
#    rn   value
# 1:  1 a_b_b_a
# 2:  2 c_c_d_e
# 3:  3 f_g_h_i
# 4:  4     j_k
```

The basic idea is to start with a "long" `data.table`, remove the `NA` values, and paste together the remaining values.

It makes a *big* difference where you use `na.omit` in terms of speed for this particular example.

---

#### Update

Here are some benchmarks using the same sample data (100K rows) [I shared at a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26738304/1270695).

These are the functions I tested:

```
AM <- function() {
  na.omit(data.table(
    rn = rep(1:nrow(df), ncol(df)), 
    val = unlist(df, use.names = FALSE)))[, paste(val, collapse = "_"), by = rn]
}

AK <- function() {
  df[is.na(df)] <-''
  gsub("^_+|_+$|_+(?=_)", "", do.call(paste,c(df, sep="_")), perl=TRUE)
}

RS <- function() {
  s <- split(df[!is.na(df)], row(df)[!is.na(df)])
  vapply(s, paste, character(1L), collapse = "_", USE.NAMES=FALSE)
}
```

And the results:

```
microbenchmark(AM(), AK(), RS(), times = 50)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#  AM()  819.4639  925.1636 1020.5084  979.6239 1118.8065 1384.873    50
#  AK()  490.6802  495.5576  559.4551  508.0861  602.8413 1192.798    50
#  RS() 1419.8630 1540.5424 1680.6115 1622.7701 1786.9931 2424.541    50
```

Comment: Hmm, Interesting question considering the days' previous events. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `vapply` on a list with the NA values removed.  This seems to be safe.

```
> s <- split(df[!is.na(df)], row(df)[!is.na(df)])
> vapply(s, paste, character(1L), collapse = "_", USE.NAMES=FALSE)
[1] "a_b_b_a" "c_c_d_e" "f_g_h_i" "j_k"
```

Comment: This answer is not foolproof yet. What about single `NA`s or `NA`s in the first column? Still some more `gsub`bing to do :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto -  I went a different direction altogether.  This is probably a lot safer

Comment: Not sure that I would consider it an *altogether* different route. Conceptually it shares some attributes of my answer: create two vectors where one is used to group the values that need to be pasted together. Yours is a literal split + apply + combine in base R, while I do the same with "data.table". But +1 for the edits and a creative use of `row` that I hadn't thought of :-) @akrun's answer is still the fastest so far though, when tested with the [sample dataset at my earlier answer from today](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26738304/1270695) (See my update.)